# How to check the status of the sent email when using emailext plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm using the email Extension plugin for Jenkins 2.332.3 but when I get errors with the configuration of the email Extension my build still goes successful even if I get for example

> AuthenticationFailedException message: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful

Is there a way to get build failure if I have incorrect configurations of emailext?
My stage:

```
emailext(
                       attachmentsPattern: "test.txt",
                       subject: "Test",
                       body: "Example test",
                       replyTo: 'test@test.com'
               )
```

When I have configurations valid I get

> DEBUG SMTP: message successfully delivered to mail server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I briefly checked the source code of the plugin and this doesn't seem doable. All the errors are caught and handled gracefully. Check [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/emailext/ExtendedEmailPublisher.java#L617). Also, the execution of the plugin doesn't even return a status code. Check [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/emailext/EmailExtStep.java#L250).

So AFAIU I don't see a way to know whether the email was sent.

**Update**

After thoroughly checking the code I observed that there is an option to execute a postscript after sending a mail. This script can be specified globally or within the pipeline. So I came up with a very hacky solution with some groovy. Basically, after sending the mail you can capture the response from the SMTP server. This response will have some details you can use to determine whether it's a success or a failure.

On success, you will see a response like the one below.(I used Gmail SMTP server here)

```
250 2.0.0 OK  1655253667 cc23-20020a05622a411700b00304f98ad3c1sm7772402qtb.29 - gsmtp
```

On Authentication failure, you should see something like the below.

```
535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials q18-20020a05622a04d200b002f906fc8530sm8752555qtx.46 - gsmtp
```

As I mentioned earlier the pipeline simply swallows all the errors that are thrown and from the script, there is no way to access the current build context. Hence as a workaround, I wrote the response to a file and then marked the status of the Job based on this. Please refer to the following pipeline.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('MailAndFail') {
            steps {
                script{
                    echo "Starting Mailing"
                    def script = "String response = transport.getLastServerResponse();println \"Mail Response: \" + response;File file = new File(\"/var/jenkins_home/workspace/EMAIEXT2222/MailResponse.txt\");file.write response"
                    emailext(
                       to: "test@gmail.com",
                       subject: "Test",
                       body: "Example test",
                       replyTo: 'test@test.com',
                       postsendScript: "$script"
                    )
                   sh "cat MailResponse.txt"
                   def response = readFile(file: 'MailResponse.txt')
                   if(!response.contains("2.0.0 OK")) {
                       echo "BUILD FAILURE!!!!"
                       currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                   }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Make sure you change the file write path to a directory in the workspace `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/EMAIEXT2222`. Also, the print statements in the script will not be shown in the build console. You can see them in the Jenkins log. Also, make sure you approve the groovy script if you get an error that says the script doesn't have permission to execute. You can do this from here: http://JENKINSHOST/scriptApproval/

Comment: So there is no way to trigger build failure if I receive an error even they handled in the plugin, is that what you're saying right?

Comment: Yes, unless you read the console output. (Not a good idea)

Comment: Exactly , I don't want to read console output cause of vulnerabilities problems :/

Comment: @wsn I had a closer look at the plugin and found a possible workaround. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: That wouldn't be a solution for me because I don't want to approve any insecure thing in Jenkins. 
I'm trying a new approach using 
def scriptFinal = sh(script: emailext(
                       to: "test@gmail.com",
                       subject: "Test",
                       body: "Example test",
                       replyTo: 'test@test.com'), returnStatus: true)
                    println("STATUS CODE")
                    println ${scriptFinal} 
but i'm getting an error saying that my script is null. Is there any possibility to use something like that ?

Comment: @wsn as I mentioned earlier the plugin doesn't return anything upon execution. It will return null always irrespective of the status.